# Compiling/linking g++ using -m32 flag on 64bit System -> manually add -ldl?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, 32bit-64bit

It was a long long way, but I managed to include a shared file (libpi_pi_gcs2.so) included into C++ code under Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit. Now as the dust is saddled I have a question left... let me summarize:

I copied libpi_pi_gcs2.so in usr/local/lib.

Trying to compile main.cpp with

```
g++ -Wall -o test main.cpp -lpi_pi_gcs2
```

faild, returning

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libpi_pi_gcs2.so when searching for -lpi_pi_gcs2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpi_pi_gcs2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I talked with my flatmate, and he guessed maybe the shared library is only 32bit compatible.
Using `-m32` let me take a step forward! But yielding new errors.

I googled and it seemed like I needed C32 std libraries. And I installed:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Again the old error messages disappeared and new one arose, after googling around I installed:

```
apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Trying to compile it now using

```
g++ -Wall -o test -m32 main.cpp -lpi_pi_gcs2
```

Let to the error messages:

```
//usr/local/lib/libpi_pi_gcs2.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libpi_pi_gcs2.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
//usr/local/lib/libpi_pi_gcs2.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

The solution was the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -o test -m32 main.cpp -lpi_pi_gcs2 -ldl
```

Now my question:

Is it necessary to explicitly state -ldl i.e. link with libdl.so because the -m32 flag declares everything what follows to be 32bit and hence the linker would without explicitly 
writing -ldl search for a 32bit libdl.so? I guess mine is 64 bit I am working on a 64bit system.

What do you think? More details and background informations are appreciated.

Greetings,

newandlost

Comment: I guess `nm /usr/local/lib/libpi_pi_gcs2.so | grep dlsym` shows `U dlsym`?

Comment: you always need to specify -ldl explicitly. It has nothing to do with -m32 switch. In this case, because of -m32 switch linker will link against 32 bit compatible libdl and libpi_pi_gcs2.